# Loop through a list of indicators to add to a data frame

Tags: python, technical-indicator, pandas-ta

Using pandas-ta library on python 3.10.

I'm trying to write a function that gets a data frame and a list of indicator names as strings,
then for each name in the list, add it as an indicator to the data frame.

For example, trying to do something like this:

```
import pandas_ta as ta

df = pd.DataFrame(data=BTC-USD)
indicators = ['rsi', 'obv']

for x in indicators:
    df[f'{x}'] = ta.x(df['close'])
```

for reference, to add an rsi indicator:

```
df['rsi'] = ta.rsi(df['close'])
```

So the issue is, that when trying to run the loop, I get an Attribute error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas_ta' has no attribute 'x'
```

Any ideas on how to get around it maybe?
I'm fairly new to python so if there's an obvious way that im missing, pardon me

this is one of the data frames im getting this issue on:
https://easyupload.io/x952ul

[this is what the csv looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUOzy.png)

I'll edit again if I see a better way to share the csv here.

Comment: What does `ta` stand for in the examples. Did you do `import pandas_ta as ta`?

Comment: replace `'any dataframe that has the date/time as index and a closing price'` with an example dataframe.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DeeraWijesundara Yes, I did. Updated the post to show it, thanks

Comment: @D.L Updated the post. Thanks!